# Linux find/search root partition ONLY?

Tags: linux, find, partitioning, search

Say I need to do:

```
find / -name somefile.txt
```

and say root partition `/` is mounted on `/dev/sda5`; however, let's say I also have 250GB partitions (`/dev/sda6`, `/dev/sda7`) mounted in `/media` - AND another location that I cannot currently remember. Say, also, that I know the file I'm looking for is on `/dev/sda5`.

Obviously, the above command will also descend in `/media` and that other directory which represent the big partitions, wasting time in looking for the file in the wrong place.

Is there a way to instruct find (or other command) to search *only* `/` on `/dev/sda5`, and NOT to descend to directories if they are on different partitions?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the `-xdev` argument to find

> -xdev  Don’t descend directories on other filesystems.

Comment: Thanks much - just for reference, the syntax would be:
<pre>find / -xdev -name somefile.txt</pre>

Comment: For mac users: find -x / -name somefile.txt

Comment: Searching the manpage for `--one-file-system` a la `du` did me no good either. At least they both begin with `-x` I suppose. And it means "cross devices" I think.

Answer (score 4):

The POSIX standard [defines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_05) the `-xdev` ”primary“:

> it shall cause find not to continue descending past directories that have a different device ID

This is implemented in GNU's `find` (i.e. the [findutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/); [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Filesystems.html#Filesystems)).
GNU `find` also allows you to use `-mount` as ”*an alternate name for `-xdev`, for compatibility with some other versions of find.*“

On BSD systems and macOS the option is `-x` instead. They (imho confusingly) call `-xdev` to be ”*deprecated*“. You can, however, use `-mount` instead. [manpages of [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find) and [macOS](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/find/)]

#### other tools, just FYI

If you're using [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) (`rg`) like `rg --files`, you can  use the `--one-file-system` option, which does the same like *find*'s `-xdev` option.